# Что не так c решением на цикл for?

Tags: java

Имеем задачу:

> Есть два числа, которые задаются пользователем через консоль (назовем
> эти два числа `a` и `b`).     Используя цикл `for`, вывести все числа из
> диапазона между `a` и `b`, которые делятся на `5` без остатка, но при этом
> не делятся на `10` без остатка.

Например, число `15` подходит под наше условие
(делится на `5` без остатка и не делится на `10` без остатка), но число `20` не подходит под наше условие
(делится на `5` без остатка и делится на `10` без остатка). **Сами числа `a` и `b` в диапазоне не учитывать.**
Если `a >= b` вывести сообщение `"Некорректный ввод"`.

Пример:

Вводим в консоли: `7 78`

Вывод: `15 25 35 45 55 65 75`

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    int b = sc.nextInt();
    if (a >= b) {
        System.out.println("Некорректный ввод");
    }
   // a = a + 1;
   //b = b - 1; 
    for (; a < b; a++) {

        if (a % 5 == 0 && a % 10 != 0) {
            System.out.print(a + " ");

        }
    }
```

В чем вопрос!?

```
a = 5, b = 50 ==> Expected: 15 25 35 45  Actual: 5 15 25 35 45
```

Тест не проходит.

Ничего умнее, чем изменить переменные перед циклом я не придумал, тест проходит, но у меня ощущение, что это не особо корректно.

Как правильнее реализовать решение?

Comment: с какого числа начинается этот цикл - ``for (; a < b; a++)``? А с какого нужно начинать?

Comment: @Эникейщик если ввести а, не компилируеться. работает, если оставить без начального значения, либо ввести a=a+1

Comment: @Эникейщик получаеться надо начитать for ( a = a + 1 , b = b - 1 ;  a < b; a++) /// а как нибудь по другому это можно реализовать?

Comment: @Эникейщик пишет Not a statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    int b = sc.nextInt();
    if (a >= b) {
        System.out.println("Некорректный ввод");
    }

    for (int i = a + 1; i < b; i++) {
        if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 10 != 0) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
```

Или так, чтобы в случае некорректного ввода даже не входить в цикл:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    int b = sc.nextInt();
    if (a >= b) {
        System.out.println("Некорректный ввод");
    } else {
        for (int i = a + 1; i < b; i++) {
            if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 10 != 0) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```